# Can I reference another entry in a numbered list?

Tags: microsoft-word

If I have a numbered list, is there a way I can reference an entry in the numbered list?  So for example if I want to say:

> 1. Do this
> 2. Do that
> 3. Do the other
> 4. If x, then go again from **2.**

... can I make the highlighed **2.** into a reference so that if I insert something else into the list after **1.**, it will automatically be updated to **3.**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a way to do it.  Go to `References | Cross-reference`, and select `Numbered item`.  Select the paragraph item to reference and it will reference it.

Unfortunately it still won't be updated automatically.  When the numbered list changes, you'll need to remember to tell Word to update the references by selecting all (Ctrl-A) and pressing F9.

Comment: If you set the “Update fields before printing” option, Word will do this whenever you print, which may be good enough.

Comment: @Scott nah, this document isn't for printing.